# djangoのプロジェクトをgit管理したい

Tags: python, git, django

`django`のプロジェクトを`git`で管理したいのですが、以下の位置で大丈夫でしょうか。

```
mysite/
    .git
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

また、`django`において`.gitignore`に登録しておくべきものはなんでしょうか。

Comment: [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/)を使うと目的に合った`.gitignore`を自動生成してくれます。`Django`と入れてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

#### djangoプロジェクトのgit管理

プロジェクト単体をgit管理する分には正しい配置です。

djangoのプロジェクト、今回の場合で言う`mysite`以外にも、その他ファイルを追加したい場合は多く存在しますが、常に管理したいディレクトリの一番上に配置すれば問題ありません。
.git以下全てを管理しますので。

#### djangoプロジェクト基本の`.gitignore`

gitignore.ioというサービスから、指定したサービス上でgit管理するための.gitignoreテンプレートをダウンロードすることができます。

以下がdjangoのテンプレートです

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/linux,django

### Django ###
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
media

# If your build process includes running collectstatic, then ...
```